# Do we need to perform error check on TimeZone.getTimeZone

Tags: java, android

When I get a TimeZone for a system says

`TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam")`

Will it work across all platforms like PC, Android, ...?

Do I need to check against `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs`?

As `TimeZone.getTimeZone` returns GMT instead of null, if the passed in parameter ("Europe/Amsterdam" in our case) is not available in that platform.

The ID I'm going to use can be found from here : http://david.uebelacker.ch/2010/05/13/java-retrive-locale-and-timezone-from-request/